# Probability of a number occurring given restrictions

Tags: excel

I am limited to only using

```
SUM
RAND
RANDBETWEEN
COUNT
COUNTIF
ROUNDDOWN
```

I have been able to only complete this using a lookup function and a VBA.

If there is a 40% chance of an event occurring depict the event occurring as 1 and the event not occurring as 0. Given that the probability of the event is in cell A1 (40%) and can be manually changed to a different probability as to affect the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `RANDBETWEEN(1,100)` function to simulate the probability. If there is a `x%` probability, you check if the generated numeber is <= to x, if it is you print 1, else 0.

`=IF(RANDBETWEEN(0,100)<=40,0,1)`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Would that give me a certain distribution I am looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to this
=LOOKUP(RAND(),{0,0.6,0.4;0,0,"1"})

Where the probability of a 0 occurring is 60% and a 1 occurring is 40%

Comment: What is your goal, your final output? If you want to simulate an event with a certain probability you can use `=IF(RANDBETWEEN(0,100)<=40,0,1)` and 40 can be replaced with a cell value.

Comment: Sorry it's very late. Thank you HAHAHA that works perfectly. Why didn't I think of that.. ahhhh